# How can I make my Google News Alerts more specific?

Tags: google-news

I have alerts set for specific places. Let's call them a street, A Road, and a town, Port B.

I routinely get alerts for articles that feature the word port (" ... in this busy port town...") and the last name B (" ... said Mayor John B...") but are in no way related to the town of Port B. Worse, on my A Road alert, I get hits for A Street, A Avenue, and so on, and because A is a last name as well, for people with that last name, and many articles about residents of a town called A Park, if the word road, street, avenue, highway etc is in the article (and often it is, even to say that John C lives on D road in A Park.)

How can I tweak these alerts to say I only want Port and B to be right next to each other in the article? That I care about A road, but not A street or A avenue or articles that feature both A and some synonym for road? I understand the value of all this flexibility when someone is doing an ad-hoc search and can't remember if it's street or road, but it makes my alerts much less useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I was setting up another alert and I noticed that some of my two word phrases are in quotes. I edited these two alerts from `Port B` to `"Port B"` and from `A Road` to `"A Road"` and the nonsense "hits" have stopped.

I didn't see anything about using quotes on the page for setting up alerts, but this appears to work.